# How a simple graph could be designed?

Tags: xaml, uwp

In UWP, there seems no graph control. Any idea to have a simple graph control like shown. Which control will be appropriate to draw a graph like this, accepting some x-y value pairs? Any code sample or idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are chart controls provided by the community, check the [WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/), which provides `Area Chart` controls.

It isn't particularly difficult if you want to make one yourself.

You can draw a polygon shape by defining its point collection, the follow XAML code defines 4 points [10, 200], [60, 140], [130, 140], [180,200] and its fill color.

```
<Polygon Fill="LightBlue"
     Points="10,200,60,140,130,140,180,200" />
```

And this is what is rendered:
[image]

`Path` is more versatile than polygon, that you can define more complex path segments than just strait lines, but for your requirement you can just do it with a `Polygon` shape.

Reference: [Draw shapes in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/shapes).

See also [XAML vector-based drawing sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Drawing-bfc39296)

**Edit: you need to draw the labels too if you want to draw the chart yourself, but again, that isn’t particularly difficult.**